# Web fonts merge(combining)

Tags: css, fonts

I am using 'Poppins' font in different variations(Regular,light,bold) on my website

In css it will look like this:

```
/* Popins 300 */ 
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Popins';
  font-display: swap;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Popins'), local('Popins');
  url('/fonts/popins/popins-300.woff2') format('woff2'), 
  url(/fonts/popins/popins-300.woff') format('woff'), 
  url('/fonts/popins/popins-300.ttf') format('truetype');
}

/* Popins 500 */ 
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Popins';
  font-display: swap;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Popins'), local('Popins');
  url('/fonts/popins/popins-500.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url(/fonts/popins/popins-500.woff') format('woff'), 
  url('/fonts/popins/popins-500.ttf') format('truetype');
}

/* Popins 700 */ 
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Popins';
  font-display: swap;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Popins'), local('Popins');
  url('/fonts/popins/popins-700.woff2') format('woff2'), 
  url(/fonts/popins/popins-700.woff') format('woff'), 
  url('/fonts/popins/popins-700.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

The above code will fetch 3 different http requests(each font).

Is it possible to merge(combaine) these different font weights into one file?

For example :

1. popins.ttf -> all the  variations of ttf font combined
2. popins.woff -> all the  variations of woff font combined
3. popins.woff2 -> all the  variations of woff2 font combined

I would like to make single http request and use the different font variations.

** Using base64 is not an option as it is not being cached **

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you care about IE11, then just load the `woff` font format. All the other ones are not needed. If you don't care about IE11, then just load `woff2` and ignore everything else. Beyond that, I wouldn't bother with this kind of micro-optimization and make sure your site runs HTTP2 instead.

Comment: Each Browser loads only the format that it uses. The 3 requests happen for the 3 different `font-weight: 300|500|700`. But I think, merging might not be possible. Example: for the char "a", there is one slot in the font-file, if you try to merge them together, how should the OS which one to use?

Comment: As nito said, the 3 requests happen due to each font weight loading...

Comment: Possible: yes. Tricky: quite. Legal? maybe, but probably not. Practical or even sensiblel? No, not in the slightest. Web fonts already get downloaded concurrently, the browser does not "download one, then another after it's done", it just downloads them all at the same time,so combining them into a single font can actually make your time-to-first-render _take longer_ if you combine them. Just don't do it. Number of HTTP request is _not_ your bottleneck. Don't optimize for it until it is.

Comment: How can i do it then?

Comment: The answer is... you don't need to do that. All of these "site scanners" that tell you need to "reduce / limit http requests" are very outdated. If your site runs HTTP2, you don't really need to worry about the number of HTTP requests. So, if you care about performance, then spend your effort towards making sure your site runs on HTTP2.